# How to make user to see Azure blob storage file being downloaded instead of downloading the complete stream in network tab itself in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a download button which user clicks to download a media file from Azure blob storage. I was expecting it to get download straightaway and user can see the download progress but instead, it is not downloading until the request gets completed.

[image]

As you can see in the above figure It's taking almost 30 seconds to download the stream and then the user is seeing the downloaded file. Could you please someone guide me in achieving the behavior shown in the below image

[image]

I am using file-saver.js for  saving file in Angular

```
this.downloadMediaService.downloadAsset(assetId).then((httpResponse) => {
        const {body: blob} = httpResponse;
        this.mediaBlob = blob;
        Filesaver.saveAs(blob, this.assetName);
      });
    }
```

Comment: Hi ark, if any of the solutions below can help with your problem, could you please mark it as "accepted". This can be beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know how many bytes you have downloaded when you download file from Azure blob, you can use the sdk `@azure/storage-blob` to implement it.

For example

1. install sdk

```
npm install @azure/storage-blob
npm install crypto-js --save
npm install @types/crypto-js --save-dev
```

2. Code

```
import {BlobServiceClient,AnonymousCredential,newPipeline } from '@azure/storage-blob';
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
...



downlaod(){
 // genereate access token



const accountname =" storage account name";
  const key="storage account key";
  const start = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (15 * 60 * 1000));
  const end = new Date(new Date().getTime() + (30 * 60 * 1000));
const signedpermissions = 'rwdlac';
  const signedservice = 'b';
  const signedresourcetype = 'sco';
  const signedexpiry = end.toISOString().substring(0, end.toISOString().lastIndexOf('.')) + 'Z';
  const signedProtocol = 'https';
  const signedversion = '2018-03-28';



  const StringToSign =
      accountname + '\n' +
      signedpermissions + '\n' +
      signedservice + '\n' +
      signedresourcetype + '\n' +
       '\n' +
      signedexpiry + '\n' +
       '\n' +
      signedProtocol + '\n' +
signedversion + '\n';

var str =CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(StringToSign,CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key));
var sig = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(str);




 const sasToken =`sv=${(signedversion)}&ss=${(signedservice)}&srt=${(signedresourcetype)}&sp=${(signedpermissions)}&se=${encodeURIComponent(signedexpiry)}&spr=${(signedProtocol)}&sig=${encodeURIComponent(sig)}`;
  const containerName="test";

            const pipeline =newPipeline (new AnonymousCredential(),{
            retryOptions: { maxTries: 4 }, // Retry options
            userAgentOptions: { userAgentPrefix: "AdvancedSample V1.0.0" }, // Customized telemetry string
            keepAliveOptions: {
                // Keep alive is enabled by default, disable keep alive by setting false
                enable: false
            }
            });

            const blobServiceClient =new BlobServiceClient(`https://${accountname}.blob.core.windows.net?${sasToken}`,
                                                             pipeline  )
            const containerClient =blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName)
            const blob =containerClient.getBlockBlobClient("SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4")
           const r= await blob.getProperties()
           const totalSize = r.contentLength
             blob.download(null,null,{onProgress: (ev) => 


               console.log("You have download "+ ev.loadedBytes +" bytes\nThe process:"+ev.loadedBytes/totalSize ) }



              ).then(response =>  response.blobBody.then(b => {



console.log(b.size)
// save file
}))






}
```

[image]

Comment: My requirement is not to track progress in our app - it should just act as a link directly to the file, which the browser should interpret as a download. So in Chrome, it would show the bar across the bottom of the browser window with the file in it, downloading, while the user can continue using the site as normal rather than waiting for the request to get completed and then see the downloaded file. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: @ark According to my understanding, you want to generate the download link then your customer can directly click the link to download file. If so, you just need to generate sas toke then concatenate the blob url and sas token

Answer (score 0):

With the SDK, you can create a SAS (shared access signature) link that authorizes a user to get the file directly from Azure blob storage. The added benefit of this is that your website or app doesn't need to download it before sending it to the user. That way it also appears in the bottom download bar of the browser.

I only have example code in c# but the steps should be universal:

- Make a new `SharedAccessBlobPolicy`
- Set the `SharedAccessStartTime` to an hour before the authorization to download (to avoid being held back by azure time drift)
- Do a `GetSharedAccessSignature(policyObject)` on the blob
- Get the link by a concatenating the `blob.Uri` and the shared access signature
- Send this link to the browser to redirect to. Using `target="_blank"` on the link makes sure you stay on the previous page and still get the user to download